# How do you update the YUM package manager repositories?

Tags: yum, tmux

I have a new install of Red Hat and I'm trying to do a "`yum install tmux`" but it is throwing a *no package available* error:

```
[root@PSCHQVP20017 ~]# yum install tmux
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
No package tmux available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not specify the distribution you are using. I guess it is rhel/centos 5 or 6: if so, you just need to add the proper [EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) to your YUM configuration and then

```
yum update
yum install tmux
```

No need to download/compile it manually.

Comment: how do u add a *epel repository*? and why doesnt yum just grab it from the central server with all these packages? why do i have to add in "new" ones all the time.

Comment: you need to add a new repository when the ones from your official distribution do not include the package you want; sometimes it is because the package is too new, sometimes because it is not populare, etc.<br>EPEL, in this case, is a "semi-official" repository being maintaned by Fedora developers: "Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (or EPEL) is a Fedora Special Interest Group that creates, maintains, and manages a high quality set of additional packages for Enterprise Linux, including, but not limited to, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), CentOS and Scientific Linux (SL), Oracle Linux (OL)."

Comment: @duckx, as far as the "central server where all these packages are," that's what a repository *is*.  So you have to tell it where the central server *is* that has the packages on it that you are interested in.  (And if you didn't know that before, try reading the above comment again and it will now make more sense.)

Comment: that installs 1.8 which is not the latest :(

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to install "unofficial" software, specially on "enterprise" distributions or any sort of machine with critical jobs. You are taking over the full responsibility of security (and other) fixes, and keeping it in synch with the rest of the system's software (libraries, configuration, security configuration, ...). Look for alternatives, check what your distribution might have to say on the particular package. They might be excluding it due to unsolvable problems of some sort, perhaps licensing (that might or not be a problem to you, as a final user or due to the legal situation in your jurisdiction) or even security problems.

Answer (score 1):

To add repo: [Adding, Enabling, and Disabling a Yum Repository](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html)

For `tmux`:

```
wget https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz
tar xzvf libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz
cd libevent-2.0.21-stable
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

then:

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/tmux/tmux-code tmux
cd tmux
sh autogen.sh
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

Reference: [Installing tmux on CentOS 6.2](http://elroyjetson.org/dev-notes/centos/installing-tmux-on-centos-6-2)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo snap install tmux --classic
```

By this way, you can install with a simple command, no need to update lib or yum repo or system.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a red hat satellite in your environment environment or do you have a valid subscription for this installation?
If so you might be able to use EPEL and other reps provided by Red Hat.